# Setting benchtime when using testing.Benchmark() directly

Tags: go

In Go, I'm running [testing.Benchmark](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#Benchmark) manually in `main()` like so:

```
func main() {
  br := testing.Benchmark(BenchmarkConnectionOpen)
  fmt.Println(br.String() + br.MemString())
}
```

What I'd like to do is set the "benchtime" for all benchmarks. I understand that when testing (eg running `go test`), this is passed in as a flag like this:

```
-benchtime=100x
```

But how do I set this flag when I'm just running in main()? I've tried `flag.Set()` (below) but no dice.

```
flag.Set("test.benchtime", "100x")
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! The docs had nudged me but took a moment to piece it together. The docs:

```
// If f depends on testing flags, then Init must be used to register
// those flags before calling Benchmark and before calling flag.Parse.
//
// If f calls Run, the result will be an estimate of running all its
// subbenchmarks that don't call Run in sequence in a single benchmark.
```

This translates to:

```
func main() {
  testing.Init()
  flag.Parse()
  br := testing.Benchmark(BenchmarkConnectionOpen)
  fmt.Println(br.String() + br.MemString())
}
```

Then run with:

```
go run main.go  -test.benchtime 100x
```